# How to repair/cover dents on linoleum/vinyl kitchen floors?

Tags: flooring, kitchens

I am not sure what kind of kitchen flooring I have. It looks like tiles but they are not real. Linoleum or vinyl? I don't know the difference. See pic below.
The 'tiles' have dents on them from heavy kitchen stuff falling on them. Another pic below shows one.

How do I repair these tiles so the dents look less visible? I want to cover or fill them with some kind of material like potty for sheetrock. Whatever product is available at Home Depot or Amazon would be helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: About the only way to repair, is to find pieces of matching design.  Using a very sharp knife(box cutter type) cut though both layers.  Remove the damage layer and glue new piece down.  Hopefully the old floor is not glued down.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is sheet vinyl or also known as linoleum.

When it gets dings or cuts, there is no way to repair those blemishes.

Generally when the floor is beyond your satisfaction, it is replaced.

Newr LVP or LVT can be installed right over the old linoleum. Ceramic tile can be installed over as well when the floor is cleaned, lightly scuffed and a modified thin set is used.